# "No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

So I am reworking a script to include prepared statements. It was working fine before, but now I am getting "No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement" when the script runs. What is the issue here?

```
<?php
require_once("models/config.php");


$firstname = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['firstname']));
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $firstname);
$surname = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['surname']));
$surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $surname);
$address = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['address']));
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $address);
$gender = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['gender']));
$gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $gender);
$city = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['city']));
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $city);
$province = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['province']));
$province = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $province);
$phone = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['phone']));
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $phone);
$secondphone = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['secondphone']));
$secondphone = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $secondphone);
$postalcode = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['postalcode']));
$postalcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $postalcode);
$email = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email']));
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $email);
$organization = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['organization']));
$organization = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $organization);
$inriding = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['inriding']));
$inriding = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $inriding);
$ethnicity = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['ethnicity']));
$ethnicity = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $ethnicity);
$senior = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['senior']));
$senior = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $senior);
$student = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['student']));
$student = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $student);


$order= "INSERT INTO persons (firstname, surname, address, gender, city, province,  postalcode, phone, secondphone, email, organization, inriding, ethnicity, senior, student_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $order);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssd", $firstname, $surname, $address, $gender, $city, $province, $postalcode, $phone, $secondphone, $email, $organization, $inriding, $ethnicity, $senior, $student);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 
echo $stmt->error;

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$stmt);
if ($result === false) {
echo "Error entering data! <BR>";
echo mysqli_error($mysqli);
 } else {
echo "User $firstname added <BR>";
 }
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My... eyes...... are......... bleeding............

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have only bound four arguments, by the control string "sssd", but you have many parameters. When binding variables with mysqli, you need one character for each parameter, for example:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssdsssssssssdd", $firstname, $surname, $address, 
    $gender, $city, $province, $postalcode, $phone, $secondphone, $email, 
    $organization, $inriding, $ethnicity, $senior, $student);
```

(I'm assuming senior and student are integers, and need the "d" code.)

You don't need to treat any of your variables with mysqli_real_escape_string() -- that's the point of using parameters. If you do escaping as well, you'll get literal backslash characters in your data in the database.

And you never need to use htmlspecialchars() in any case - you would use that when outputting to HTML, not when inserting to the database. You're going to get literal sequences like `&amp;` in your data in the database.

---

Re your next error:

> "Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_stmt could not be converted to string in..."

This is caused by the following:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$stmt);
```

That function expects the second argument to be a string, a new SQL query. But you've already prepared that query, so you need the following:

```
$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: So to summarize.... I can basically turn each variable at the beginning to '$firstname = trim($_POST['firstname']);' for example and get rid of the rest. 

And my control string has to have 15 characters - one for each parameter?

Comment: Right, the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) says, "The number of variables and length of string types must match the parameters in the statement." That probably isn't written as clearly as it should be.

Comment: Solution worked perfectly. Thanks for not only assisting with the code but also explaining the logic behind it - which allows novices like to me get a better understanding and help me become better at PHP. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @Bill Karwin , I've just noticed something in my record insert. The gender is simply inserting a 0, when it should be inserting either Male or Female (it is pulling the value from a drop down menu). 

My other drop downs are inserting correctly, so I thought change the fourth character in the control string to 's' would work, but I get an error saying "Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_stmt could not be converted to string in..." What might the problem be?

Comment: Correction: although I am getting that error the record is inserting properly as I want.

Comment: Always a pleasure reading the way you outline a given issue Bill. You have my vote on this one. The part about *"That function expects the second argument to be a string..."* is what I've asked myself before but never did find an actual solution to a problem I once had, but had figured it out in the end; cheers.